# Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

many developers.
This is my first question and I can't solve this.

I'm using AWS For to deploy out webapp and projects.
and now I just want to deploy so tiny project.
(like just **basic django project**)

I already test this in local(with "python manage.py runserver").
and build & run dockerfile.

But Deploying is failed with AWS continually.
I write Dockerfile and I use it.
But AWS says to me
**"cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory"**
and I don't understand what it says.

This is my code in DockerFile

```
FROM        {{mydockerId}}/myproject:base

COPY        . /srv/FestivalMusicList
# static directory setting

RUN         cp -f /srv/FestivalMusicList/.config/nginx.conf     /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&\
            cp -f /srv/FestivalMusicList/.config/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/ &&\
            rm -f /etc/nginx/site-enabled/* &&\
            ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx-app.conf     /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

RUN         cp /srv/FestivalMusicList/.config/supervisord.conf  /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
RUN         mkdir /var/log/celery

EXPOSE      80
```

This is error

```
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.308Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_festival_music_list/Command 04_setdata_genre] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.310Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_festival_music_list/Command 04_setdata_genre] : Completed activity.
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.310Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_festival_music_list] : Completed activity.
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.310Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.328Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.328Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/InfraCleanEbExtension] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.329Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0/InfraCleanEbExtension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /tmp.
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.329Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 0 completed
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.329Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage1] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.329Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-05T15:05:33.331Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-05T15:05:39.636Z] INFO  [3747]  - [Application deployment app-cdf1-190406_000132@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  01a93e5ed8e11b0c76133e5e446764a8ec95ddd1db144be5d3fceca9fd6c0813
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Fri Apr  5 15:05:39 UTC 2019:. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  01a93e5ed8e11b0c76133e5e446764a8ec95ddd1db144be5d3fceca9fd6c0813
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Fri Apr  5 15:05:39 UTC 2019:. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Elastic Beanstalk? If so, you need the `Dockerrun.aws.json` at your root directory.

An example of its contents:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "janedoe/image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "1234"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx",
  "Entrypoint": "/app/bin/myapp",
  "Command": "--argument"
}
```

For more information: [Official Doc's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html)

Comment: I don't remember how to solve this problem that so old question.
So I can't use your suggestion. But so thanks for answer my question.
If I have a problem like this again, I'll keep that in mind~